# CannotLoadBeanClassException while trying to read properties file in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to read properties from a properties file in Spring Framework
I amusing SpringToolSuite MVC  template my code as follows

here is my project directory structure
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fw6G.png)

I am getting

`org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.iodevops.uhc.prop.JavaMailPropImpl] for bean with name 'mailProp' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.iodevops.uhc.prop.JavaMailPropImpl`

though there is the java class defined.

HomeController.java

```
package com.iodevops.uhc;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.iodevops.uhc.prop.JavaMailPropImpl;

/**
 * Handles requests for the application home page.
 */
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

    /**
     * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
        logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);

        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, locale);

        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

        model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate );

        return "home";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/mailProp", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String mailProp(@Validated JavaMailPropImpl mailProp,Model model){       
        model.addAttribute("mailPropValues", mailProp.toString());
        return "mailProp";
    }

}
```

servlet-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- 
    <beans:bean id="mailProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <beans:property name="location" value="classpath:mail.properties" />
    </beans:bean>
    -->
    <beans:bean id="mailProp" class="com.iodevops.uhc.prop.JavaMailPropImpl">
        <beans:property name="host" value="${smtp.host}" />
        <beans:property name="port" value="${smtp.port}" />
        <beans:property name="user" value="${smtp.user}" />
        <beans:property name="pass" value="${smtp.pass}" />
    </beans:bean>


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.iodevops.uhc" />
</beans:beans>
```

JavaMailPropImpl.java:

```
package com.iodevops.uhc.prop;

public class JavaMailPropImpl {
    private String host;
    private String port;
    private String user;
    private String pass;


    public String getHost() {
        return host;
    }
    public void setHost(String host) {
        this.host = host;
    }
    public String getPort() {
        return port;
    }
    public void setPort(String port) {
        this.port = port;
    }
    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }
    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
    public String getPass() {
        return pass;
    }
    public void setPass(String pass) {
        this.pass = pass;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return host + "|" + port + "|" + user + "|"+ pass;      
    }
}
```

Error Message

```
        ERROR: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Context initialization failed
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.iodevops.uhc.prop.JavaMailPropImpl] for bean with name 'mailProp' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.iodevops.uhc.prop.JavaMailPropImpl
    Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.iodevops.uhc.prop.JavaMailPropImpl] for bean with name 'mailProp' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.iodevops.uhc.prop.JavaMailPropImpl
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.creat....
....

        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.iodevops.uhc.prop.JavaMailPropImpl] for bean with name 'mailProp' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.iodevops.uhc.prop.JavaMailPropImpl
            at ....
    ....
    ....
```

Comment: clean your project by going to Project->clean

Comment: I tried clean and rebuild.. but no use.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this  Spring config :

```xml
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath*:project.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: this type of structure is required only when there is ArrayList type of properties in my bean. other wise I will get org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.util.ArrayList' to required type 'org.springframework.core.io.Resource'

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:
Maven dependency

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Add the import.

```
import javax.annotation.Resource;
```

...

```
@Resource (name="propertiesMapName") 
public Properties someProps;
```

In your spring xml application context:

```
<util:properties id="propertiesMapName" location="classpath:yourFile.properties"/>
```

You will need this namespace

```
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"

http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd
```

Comment: the error am getting is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class of my properties model class...

Comment: did you add the maven dependecy?

Comment: The solution i give you is to load a properties file, into a Properties object when spring startup the app, but I don't see the relation with what are you doing in your code, seems you are retrieving from the request the object mailProps

Comment: my intension is ... mailProp bean values to be fetched from the properties file.

Comment: @SatyaN then you can follow the steps I said before, then when spring is initialized you will have the Properties object fill with all properties of the file, and you will be able to access to any of them.